# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'practice_name' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm a beginner with Laravel (this project is version 5.4), but can't understand why this isn't working.  Here's my code setup:

HTML Form (form method="post".  Action is to "/providers"):

```
<div class="form-group">

<label for="practice_name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="practice_name" id="practice_name">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Provider Model:

```
protected $fillable = ['provider_name'];
```

ProvidersController:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    Provider::create([
        'practice_name' => request('practice_name')
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('AllProviders');
}
```

I've done a Dump and Die:

```
dd($request->all());
```

and this is what I get:

```
array:2 [
_token" => "wcCHLBR9hJhH8JS7vSc3vUjyLnjvg0Wvn8oRUnAh"
"practice_name" => "Test Provider"
]
```

My web routes look like this:

```
Route::get('/pricing', 'ProtectedPagesController@pricing');

Route::get('/providers', 'ProvidersController@index')->name('AllProviders');
Route::get('/providers/create', 'ProvidersController@create')->name('CreateProvider');
Route::post('/providers', 'ProvidersController@store')->name('StoreProvider');
Route::get('/providers/{provider}', 'ProvidersController@show');

Route::get('/patients', 'PatientsController@index')->name('AllPatients');
Route::get('/patients/{patient}', 'PatientsController@show');
```

So, my Dump and Die shows that my controller is getting the provider_name variable, yet when I execute the Create command, it's telling me that it doesn't see the value.  I am sure this is something simple, but after spending the last day and a half looking all over StackOverflow (and the rest of the web), I keep getting fixes that I've already tried.  The error that I'm getting is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'practice_name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `providers` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2018-04-09 13:45:45, 2018-04-09 13:45:45))

And I don't want to let that field be nullable in the database, because that field is mandatory.  There's no point to this controller if I make the database nullable - And furthermore, I don't see how that fixes the issue.  The form value still isn't being read into the Create function.

Hoping someone can help me here.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess you set the the field to `NOT NULL`, which requires you to set a `DEFAULT` value to it, You either set it to allow `NULL` or set a `DEFAULT` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request('practice_name')` doesn't seems to return the field value. Try this instead:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $requestValues = $request->all();
    Provider::create([
        'practice_name' => $requestValues['practice_name']
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('AllProviders');
}
```

or

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Provider::create([
        'practice_name' => $request->input('practice_name')
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('AllProviders');
}
```

You may read more on "how to read request values" in the following link:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests

Comment: That seemed to fix the problem identified in this question.  It presented another issue which I had to overcome.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ToddH Which problem it presented? If you post another question just let me know...